# Running this java game loop code to render the graphics is killing the performance

Tags: java, swing, graphics, game-loop

I have this code from this tutorial https://youtu.be/Nn8LH6T3xuc
and I can't understand why is running so slow.

There is a thread that handles the game loop and renders the graphics on screen.
Before the implementation of the render() method it runs nice..

There is a thread that handles the game loop and renders the graphics on screen.

```
public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {

    public static final int WIDTH = 420;
    public static final int HEIGHT = WIDTH / 12 * 9;
    public static final int SCALE = 2;

    private boolean running = false;
    private Thread thread;

    private BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    @Override
    public void run() {
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        final double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
        double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
        double delta = 0;
        int updates = 0;
        int frames = 0;
        long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();

        while(running) {
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;
            if(delta >= 1) {
                tick();
                updates++;
                delta--;
            }
            render();
            frames++;

            if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
                timer += 1000;
                System.out.println(updates + " Ticks, FPS "+ frames);
                updates = 0;
            }
        }
        stop();     
    } 

    private void tick() {   }

    private void render() {
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if(bs == null) {
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }

        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        //////////////////////////////////
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);

        //////////////////////////////////
        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //jframe creation etc...

        game.start();
    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        if(running) return;

        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        if(!running) return;

        running = false;
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]."